# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException thrown from Geb test

Tags: groovy, geb

I'm just getting started with Geb, and tried to execute the following Geb script from inside a groovy.console on OSX:

```
@Grapes([
   @Grab("org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:latest.release"),
   @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:latest.release")
])

import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver 

Browser.drive(new ChromeDriver(), "http://www.google.com") { 
    println $("div") 
}
```

The following are excerpts of the stacktrace:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyManagerFactory: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509 not a KeyManagerFactory
... 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure initializing default SSL context
... 
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyManagerFactory: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509 not a KeyManagerFactory
```

Is there an aspect of either the Groovy or Browser object configuration that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the actual stacktrace?  By chopping out the rest of it, it's hard to see where in the chain it is failing...

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to Geb myself and if memory serves, I had some weird errors trying to use the Chrome driver, so I fell back to the Firefox driver which worked immediately.  I'm not saying the ChromeDriver won't work, but try the Firefox one with a very simple script first.  That seems more likely to work on your first try.